# How to install from salesforce eclilpse source code

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, force.com

i'm new to salesforce and havn't yet worked in salesforce using eclipse.The situation is such that i have a salesforce app project eclipse source code.
Can any guide me about how to install salesforce app from eclipse.
And which versio of eclipse to use and all??

Any helful links would be appreciated.I'm a complete new bee to salesforce

Answer (score 0):

You can use any recent version of Eclipse with the Force.com plugin, but Salesforce provides a specialized build of eclipse at http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation . You might just want to use that if you don't have any other eclipse needs.

Comment: ok i installed windows installer 64 bit , but in the next line in the above link it says "Once you have completed installation, go to Help | Software and Workspace Center and click the "Apply" button in the dashboard tab".But i don't c any thing of that sort in Force IDE

Comment: @iBlue hmmm, I don't have access to a windows machine, so I can't be of too much more help on that front. Good Luck!